# jquery table filter script not not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, servlets

I have JSP page which displays the records fetched from mysql through java servlet. Now I want filter the obtained records using jquery. I used the following code with head section of jsp page

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js">
</script><script type= "text/javascript">{$(document).ready(function()
{$("#searchInput").keyup(function() {
    var rows = $("#fbody").find("tr").hide();
    var data = this.value.split(" ");
    $.each(data, function(i, v) {
        rows.filter(":contains('" + v + "')").show();
    });
})})};
</script>
```

The code for getting the records from servlet and displaying it in the JSP is given below

```
 <body><input id="searchInput" ><br/>


<TABLE  align="Center" border="1px" width="80%">
<thead>
<tr><th><b>User_ID</b></th>
    <th><b>User_Name</b></th>
    <th><b>Password</b></th>
    <th><b>Designation</b></th>
</tr>
</thead>
    <%Iterator itr;%>
    <%List data=(List) request.getAttribute("UserData");
    for(itr=data.iterator();itr.hasNext();)
    {%>
        <tbody id="fbody">
        <tr>
            <% String s= (String) itr.next(); %> 
            <td><%=s %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>

            <form id="edit" action="EditRecord" method="post" >
            <td><input type="hidden" name="hidden_edit" id="edit_id" value="<%=s %>"/> 
            <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="edit"> </td>
            </form>

            <td><form id="delete" action="DeleteRecord" method="post" >
            <td><input type="hidden" name="hidden_delete" id="delete_id" value="<%=s %>"/>
            <input type="submit" value="delete" name="delete"> </td>
            </form></td>    
    <%} %>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
</TABLE></body>
```

I am able to get all the records but the script is not filtering my record. Dont know where is the problem.Could any one help me out please.

Comment: try var rows = $("#fbody").find("tr"); and rows.hide(); afterwards

Comment: @Timur Thanks for your reply. But could elaborate where should I put the above line afterwards?

Comment: check the answert from @Abimbole Esuruoso it looks like you are having multiple tbody tags with same id which should not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take tbody out of your for loop.